# Combinatorics: Splitting of balls into sets.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Please check my solution of a combinatorial problem.

We have $30$ white balls and $15$ black balls. We randomly split them into $3$ groups of equal size (so there are $15$ balls in a group). What is the probability that one group contains $7$ black balls and other groups each contains 4 black balls?

My solution:

First let us count splits. Split is in fact a sequence of choices of balls. So there are ${45\choose 15} \cdot {30\choose 15}\cdot {15\choose 15}$ ways to split the balls. I am confident with this part (which does not mean it is true, of course). But I am less confident with another part - how do we count that specific choices? My attempt there are  ${15\choose 7} \cdot {15\choose 4}\cdot {15\choose 4}$ specific choices. I will not be surprised if that is true (and), but I can not clearly explain it to myself. That is why it can be completely false.

Can you please check my solution/help with the problem?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are indeed $\binom{15}{7}\cdot\binom{15}{4}\cdot\binom{15}{4}$ ways to split up the black balls among the three groups, such that there are 7 in the first group and 4 in each of the other two. But you also have to split up the white balls, putting 8 in the first group and 11 in each of the other two. So the number of ways to split the balls up with 7 black in the first group and 4 in each of the other two is $\binom{15}{7}\cdot\binom{15}{4}\cdot\binom{15}{4}\cdot\binom{30}{8}\cdot\binom{30}{11}\cdot\binom{30}{11}$.

Also, according to my reading of the question, it asked for the number of ways to have 7 black balls in *any* one of the groups, not specifically the first one.  There are 3 such choices, giving a total of $3\cdot\binom{15}{7}\cdot\binom{15}{4}\cdot\binom{15}{4}\cdot\binom{30}{8}\cdot\binom{30}{11}\cdot\binom{30}{11}$.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot! You answer seems correct to me, the thing that helped me is treating second part of the problem as splitting!